# Can $\mathbf R$ be negative in spherical coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

If so, what vector does it signify?

PS: $R =$ is the radial distance of the vector $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Answer (score 3):

No, $r$ shouldn't be negative. If it is for some reason, you restore a positive value with

$$r,\theta,\phi\leftrightarrow-r,-\theta,\pi-\phi$$

following the convention in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system.

Comment: I agree with you for the previous comment.